# jQuery 3D carousel?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, 3d, carousel

Has anyone seen a tutorial for a jQuery 3D carousel like this one?
http://web.enavu.com/demos/3dcarouselwip/

No source is given, but was wondering if anyone had tips on how to continuously circle the DIVs and resize them.

It doesn't appear to be true 3D, but resizes the DIVs based on position?

Thanks,
Juan

Answer (score 8):

Here is a [3D Carousel](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/carousel/demo/index.html) located in the jQuery UI Labs... I think it's pretty cool :)

Comment: Hi there. I just happened to land on your comment here and I was wondering if you know of a way to make the carousel less jittery on Firefox?

Comment: @malicula If you are using an older version of Firefox, check out [this post on how to enable WebGL](http://www.sitepoint.com/firefox-enable-webgl-blacklisted-graphics-card/#fbid=_AXqr3tqPcW), or maybe [this blog post](http://www.adrogen.com/blog/jquery-flicker-in-firefox/) might help - it explains how using overflow may help.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 positions that the images can be in.

Specify these, then use jQuery to animate the image between one position and the next.

Answer (score 0):

Here is jquery 3d carousel library 
https://jascarousel.github.io/jascarousel/

It allows you to create horizontal and verticle 3d carousel :)