# Infinite carousel not working in IE but working in firefox or chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

The following link of my carousel is not working as it is supposed to be in IE. However it works just fine in any other browser like chrome or firefox.

Here is the link for the same:

http://web.enavu.com/demos/3dcarouselwip/

What changes i have to make in the source code as I perfectly have gone through the code more than 10 times.

Comment: Lots of pleas for expedient help are not likely to yield the results you want. Do you really think your problems are more important than others'?

Comment: i am not saying that my problem is important than others, all i wanted was some help for my query!!
if you can help me than i would be most thankful to you, if not then please remain silent and let others do the job!!
thank you.

Comment: That attitude isn't going to get you anywhere, either.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the site you provide says it doesnt work in IE and is still a work in progress. I would suggest not trying to hack and change their code and rather choose another scroller, there are loads out there.

There are some links on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958519/jquery-3d-carousel) question...

Comment: yes, the developer had shared with me this link for getting a suitable solution to the problem..I am not hacking or trying to change the stuff. I am just looking for the solution as I have been asked for.
If you can help then I would be highly oblidged!!!