# Looking for a jquery image Plugin like this

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am searching for a jquery image plugin like this site header has. I will customized the minor things. But need a basic plugin for that. I am sure there will one like this.

http://ipadbraincase.com/

Comment: Ya but there will be Jquery plugin for this.. Its very common design..

Comment: if you think it is a common design then clearly you know how many there are and what they are -- why are you asking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that level of customization you would need to create your own.

You can start looking at [exiting image slider plugins and tutorials](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/10/20-stunning-jquery-image-sliders-and-tutorials-for-creating-your-own.html) to make your own.

Answer (score 0):

That's called a (3D) Carousel.  A quick google found me this

http://www.ajaxline.com/best-jquery-carousels-plugins

See also [jQuery 3D carousel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958519/jquery-3d-carousel)